# Como distinguir valores para su recuento Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Me pregunto si hay una manera de que pueda especificar los valores que tiene mi columna en Power BI, en mi columna tengo 2 diferentes valores, **Con horario** y **Sin horario**.

Ya obtuve los datos desde mi Excel pero al mover el campo a Valores me hace recuento total de todos sin diferenciar si existe Con horario o Sin horario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que al revisar en mi gráfica me hace un recuento total de los valores que tengo en mi columna.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como diferenciar entre los valores que tengo en mi columna.

**Actualización:**

Lo que requiero y me interesa es contar solo los valores que contenga el valor **Con horario** y este poderlo visualizar en mi gráfica.

Comment: Lo que intentas obtener ¿es un recuento de filas con valores distintos? es decir un DISTINCT COUNT?

Comment: En mi columna `Con horario / Sin horario` tengo estos valores respectivamente, lo que deseo es contar cuales tienen el valor Con horario y cuales Sin horario

Comment: @RogerTorné Al final lo que necesito es que solo me haga el recuento de los valores que contengan **Con horario** que seria lo unico que me interesa visualizar en mi grafica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debías hacer un par de medias calculadas para obtener lo que buscas:

En el menú "Modelado", le dices Nueva medida e introduces la fórmula

```
Con horario = CALCULATE(
   COUNT(Hoja1[Con horario / Sin horario])
   , FILTER(Hoja1, Hoja1[Con Horario / Sin horario] = "Con horario")
)
```

Luego creas otra medida:

```
Sin horario = CALCULATE(
   COUNT(Hoja1[Con horario / Sin horario])
   , FILTER(Hoja1, Hoja1[Con Horario / Sin horario] = "Sin horario")
)
```

Ten en cuenta que dependiendo de la configuración que tengas puesta en Power Bi, te aceptará la coma (,) como separador o bien la tendrás que cambiar por punto y coma (;).